# How to use HTML5 validation check for inputs in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, validation, vuejs2

How to use html5 `form.checkValidity()` with form of custom components in vuejs 2?

With html5 inputs, form validation works well:

```
<form name="myform" ref="formref">
  <input type="text" required /> 
  <button type="submit" @click="submitForm">Ok</button>
</form>
...
methods: {
  submitForm() {
    if (this.$refs.formref.checkValidity()) sendData();
    else showError();
  }
}
```

**But** if I use custom components,  that won't work:

```
<form name="myform" ref="formref">
  <MyCustomInputComponent :required="true" /> 
  <button type="submit" @click="submitForm">Ok</button>
</form>
```

`checkValidity()` of the form will always return `true`.

**The question**, is how should I implement `MyCustomInputComponent` to let it works with HTML5 forms validation?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Trying to validate the custom field inside the component. For this I would use `@keyup` event to fire the validation before submition. If you are using vuetify (it is a very common library) you can use the rules tag to do it.
2. Use an external [library](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/examples/custom-component.html) called veeValidate for this.